# What encoding does Camel File Component Charset support?

Tags: apache-camel

When I scan through the documentation for file component, I saw charset option support encoding. I cannot see any description or reference to encoding list it support. So, what encoding does Camel File Component Charset support?

http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports the charsets that your JRE supports at runtime.

You can find more details in the javadoc of Charset:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

And there is a standard set of charsets on all JREs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html